# Generating sequence data for recommender system in R

Tags: r, associations, cluster-analysis, sequence, recommendation-engine

I am trying to build a recommender system to recommend electives to the new students based on their core courses and historical students' data (data contain both core courses and electives).

1. I have the data as shown in this table:

[image]

2. I generated a cross-table as shown in Table2 (with no order of Term_Code)

[image]

3. I want to generate a sequence data as shown in Table3 (The combination of Course_Num:Grade should be in order with respect to Term_Code

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `aggregate(yes~Student_Num,transform(df1[2],yes=do.call(paste,c(df1[3:4],sep=":"))),paste)`

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be easier to start from Table 1 (`df1` in example below)

```
require(dplyr)
set.seed(46)

df1 <- data.frame(Term_Code = sample(2001:2003, 7, T),
                 Student_Num = sample(1:3, 7, T),
                 Course_Num = sample(1000:1003, 7, T),
                 Grade = sample(LETTERS[1:4], 7, T), stringsAsFactors = F)

# A tibble: 7 x 5
# Groups:   Student_Num [3]
#  Term_Code Student_Num Course_Num Grade Sequence
#      <int>       <int>      <int> <chr> <chr>   
#1      2001           2       1003 A     1003:A  
#2      2001           3       1002 D     1002:D  
#3      2002           3       1003 A     1003:A  
#4      2002           1       1000 A     1000:A  
#5      2001           1       1002 B     1002:B  
#6      2002           2       1002 B     1002:B  
#7      2003           1       1003 A     1003:A

df1 %>% 
    group_by(Student_Num) %>% 
    summarise(Sequence = paste(Course_Num, Grade, sep = ':', collapse = ', '))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  Student_Num Sequence              
#        <int> <chr>                 
#1           1 1000:A, 1002:B, 1003:A
#2           2 1003:A, 1002:B        
#3           3 1002:D, 1003:A
```

Comment: Thank you, Renu! I had given a lot of thought about the approach. The method is clear and concise. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Using the `tidyverse` suite of packages:

```
library(tidyverse)

# The pipe operator (%>%) makes df1 the first argument of the next function.
# It lets us look at this "in order" not nested
df1 <- data_frame(
  term_code = c(200701, 200701, 200707, 200701, 200801, 200807, 200707, 200701), 
  student_number = rep(1:3, c(4, 2, 2)),
  course_number = c(1000, 2200, 1100, 4200, 2000, 1100, 2000, 4100),
  grade = c('A','B', 'B-','C','A', 'B','C','E')
)

df1 %>%
  unite(Sequence,c(course_number, grade), sep = ":") %>%
  group_by(student_number) %>%
  summarize(
    Sequence = paste(Sequence, collapse = ", ")
  )
```

If you aren't familiar with the pipe operator or the other functions I'm using, I would call this one piece at a time so you can see what it's doing (and it's all documented at https://www.tidyverse.org/). For example,

```
df1 %>%
  unite(Sequence,c(course_number, grade), sep = ":")
```

Comment: Thank you, Melissa! this is of great help. thanks for the link to tidyverse too!

Answer (score 0):

Using reshape2 and %>% operator from dplyr

```
df <- read.csv(text="
Student_Num,1000,1100,2000,2200,4100,4200
1,A,B-,,B,,C
2,,B,A,,,
3,,,C,,E,
", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

melt(df, id.vars = "Student_Num",  value.name = 'Grade') %>%
  mutate(variable = substr(variable, 2, 5)) %>%
  filter(Grade != "") %>%
  group_by(Student_Num) %>%
  summarize(Sequence = paste0(variable, ":", Grade, collapse = ","))

#  Student_Num Sequence                    
#        <int> <chr>                       
# 1           1 1000:A,1100:B-,2200:B,4200:C
# 2           2 1100:B,2000:A               
# 3           3 2000:C,4100:E
```

Comment: Thank you, @epi99 ! I was trying to implement something similar to this. I really appreciate your inputs!